# How do I import Active Directory users into JIRA only from specific groups?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jira

A caveat to begin with - I don't actually know if what I want to do is possible, particularly because I'm not well versed with LDAP/Active Directory or JIRA.

I'm trying to integrate my shiny new installation of JIRA with my existing active directory. What I want to do is set up some specific JIRA groups (e.g. in London\Security Groups\JIRA*) and then have JIRA only import the users who have membership of those groups. However, in the directory set up page in JIRA, I don't understand how to do this. It seems to indicate that I can import users *and* groups, but not users *from* groups.

What am I missing? (apart from expert level knowledge of AD!)

**Update**

Under my domain, I have an organisational structure like this:

`London\Users`

London\Security Groups\JIRA

Under the latter organisational unit, I have a security group called "jira-users". The former contains all users.

So far I've tried the following queries and none of them have worked :

(all prefixed with `&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)"`)

`memberof=CN=jira-users,ou=London,ou=Security Groups,ou=JIRA,dc=mycompany,dc=local`

`memberof=CN=JIRA,ou=London,ou=Security Groups,dc=mycompany,dc=local`

(prefixed with just `&(objectCategory=Person)"`)

`memberof=CN=jira-users,ou=London,ou=Security Groups,ou=JIRA,dc=mycompany,dc=local`

**Completed**

The query that works is this :

`memberof=CN=jira-users,OU=JIRA,OU=Security Groups,OU=London,DC=mycompany,DC=local`

I hadn't realised that for a folder structure that is logically, left to right, London\Security Groups\JIRA, the organisational units need to be listed in reverse order.

**Further Update**

This only works when using the DirectorySearcher class for some reason, e.g.

```
DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=mycompany,dc=local");
DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry);
srch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
srch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberof=CN=jira-users,ou=London,ou=Security Groups,ou=JIRA,dc=mycompany,dc=local))";
SearchResultCollection results = srch.FindAll();
```

This doesn't work in the LDAP explorer [tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx) and subsequently, not in JIRA itself.

**Last Update**

So...for JIRA, you need to reverse the order AND remove the wildcard. Working query in the end is :

`(&(objectCategory=Person)(memberof=CN=jira-users,OU=JIRA,OU=Security Groups,OU=London,DC=mycomapny,DC=local))`

Comment: Try removing the (sAMAccountName=*) part. It is unneeded and I just read somewhere that wildcards are not allowed in this type of query.

Comment: I believe that MS AD comes with an LDAP inspector tool of sorts where you can go to that security group and find out its exact DN. THat might help determine if your query is correct. You should also make sure that the bind account you are using has the appropriate permissions, if you have not done so already.

Comment: Considering the top Google result for "LDAP inspector" is this post, I'm not sure where to look for such a thing.

Comment: With the (sAMAccountName=*) but without the memberof query I get 132 results. Without both I get nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are setting up the user directory look under the User Schema settings. You should see a "User Object Filter" field. In there you should be able to add something like this:

```
(memberOf=cn=jira-users,ou=London,dc=mydomain,dc=com)
```

This will allow you to filter based on a specific LDAP group. Of course you will need to edit the values above to reflect your own environment.

Comment: That seems to filter the users down to none at least...which is some progress. I'm not sure what the parameters should be though. Currently I have (memberof=CN=jira-users,ou=London,ou=Security Groups,ou=JIRA,dc=company,dc=com), but it's not returning anything. The ou path (whatever it's called) of the group is London\Security Groups\JIRA, but the users are all under London\Users. I've tried both, and neither seems to work. Have I misunderstood something fundamental?

Comment: My example was assuming an security group called jira-users. Maybe try  (memberOf=cn=JIRA,ou=London,dc=mydomain,dc=com), and of course, replace the mydomain and com with your own domain, right?

Comment: Done. The Security group *is* called jira-users. The query still doesn't work though.

Comment: Based on what you are telling me, I think your first one above *should* work. (memberof=CN=jira-users,ou=London,ou=Security Groups,ou=JIRA,dc=mycompany,dc=local).  Just so we're clear though, please tell me that you are replaceing the strings "mydomain" and "local" with the values for *your* domain.

Comment: OMG, the OU parameters were the wrong way round. What is this, reverse polish? :)

Comment: Seems to be, yes. I've added the working query to the main body of the question. Ta.